# Electron + vite build with static folder

Tags: electron, vite, webassembly, electron-forge

In my application there is a directory which contains three files (`module.js`, `module.wasm` and `module.worker.js`). The only way to integrate those binaries in my application is to create a HTMLScriptElement and add it to the head of my application like so:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = new URL("./bin/module.js", import.meta.url).href;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The usual `import ... from ...` or `await import(...)` notations don't work.
In development I have used the vite plugin `vite-plugin-static-copy` to get this to work by copying the entire `bin` folder.

Unfortunately when building the folder `vite build` or `electron-forge make` this copied folder doesn't appear in my `dist` files, only the `module.js` is included.

How can I get the wasm and worker file also to be included in the build folder and consequently in my electron native app?